# How to apply Azure Founder's Credit

Tags: azure

I have Azure founders' credits but not showing on my billing page, what's there is the initial $200, and I want to apply the credits to a subscription that I have the billing ownership.

I checked the billing page only to see the initial $200 credits

Comment: Ask Microsoft support. This is not related to SO

Comment: This is a grey area but on topic for SO because managing the azure resources in a startup is predominantly the developer's responsibility and this community of developers in this collective are likely to have experience in this offering from the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply the credits to an existing subscription, you can only create a new subscription using those credits.

Then as you progress through the sponsorship program new credits will be applied to that subscription. When you graduate from the program the subscription can be converted to *Pay as You Go*

> If you had existing resources in other subscriptions, then you may choose to move those services over to the sponsorship subscription that was created.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSchaller , I just contacted Azure support and they worked it out for me.